Time derivative of Heaviside step functional H[f(t)]
$\newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}$
I was doing random math when I randomly encountered a Heaviside Step Functional of a time variant function $\on{f}\left(t\right)$.

Basically returning $1$ if $\on{f}\left(t\right) > 0$, or $0$ when $\on{f}\left(t\right) \leq 0$.
My question was: is the time derivative of $\on{H}\left[\on{f}\left(t\right)\right]$ computable with the chain rule ?.
Like:


$${{\rm d} \over {\rm d}t}
\on{H}\left[\on{f}\left(t\right)\right] = \delta\left(\on{f}\left(t\right)\right)
\on{f}'\left(t\right)$$


I know that $\on{H}\left(x\right)$ is not a continuous function, thus not differentiable in the classical sense ( I mean I know some of the Dirac delta stuff ).
Moreover I have basically no knowledge about functional analysis, so I'm kinda stuck haha.

P.S.: is there a discrete version of this time derivative, maybe one that avoids eventual infinities/ill-defined situations ?.

What is "random math", and how does one "randomly encounter" any function?

Math whose context I would not like to publish online :)

@amWhy Random math is looking around different topics at once likes MSE.

Is the time derivative of $H[f(t)]$ computable with the chain rule? Yes, certainly !
Furthermore the formula you proposed is correct: $$\frac{d}{dt}H[f(t)] = \delta (f(t))f'(t)$$
The discontinuities in the Heaviside function and the Dirac delta function can indeed be avoided, by viewing these functions as the limit of certain continuous functions. For example, one may regard the Heaviside function $H(x)$ as the limit of $\frac {1}{2}(\tanh(x/\epsilon)+1) = 1/(1+e^{-2x/\epsilon})$, for $\epsilon$ going to $+0$. Another popular choice is to start with the Dirac delta function and regard it as a normalized Gaussian function with a narrow width. By integration we then see that the corresponding Heaviside function is represented by the error function.
